# Is it possible to completeley kill Docker service with container?

Tags: linux, security, docker

I mean, I have two Docker containers running on my system, but one of them does something that kills not only itself, but also an another container too. Or maybe worse - the entire virtual machine (unlikely happen, but...)

I just want to protect other containers running on the same system, so for example if one of them goes down with OOM, the rest of them aren't affected at all (and maybe also the first container restarted)

Comment: You might want to consider looking into Minikube (and Kubernetes); where you should be able to re-schedule failing containers, maybe set priorities, memory limits, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily limit the amount of memory used by each container with `--memory` and `--memory-swap` to prevent the whole machine from going down for OOM.

You can find more details on how to limit resource usage of containers at https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/